# How to create circle checkbox multiple choice exam with choice letters inside circle

Tags: templates, exam, auto-multiple-choice

I can't find any place where I can get an exam environment where I can make a multiple choice exam with circle checkbox where the options are in letters A,B,C,D and E, and these are inside the checkboxes. Please help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using some Tikz trickery it can be done. If you are using `oneparcheckboxes`, all you have to do is modify the `\checkboxchar` and `\checkedchar` commands:

```
% Make checkbox character a circle with the letter
\checkboxchar{\tikz[baseline={([yshift=-.8ex]current bounding box.center)}]\node[shape=circle,minimum size=8mm,draw] at (0,0) {\thechoice};}
% Make checked box character bold WITH surd
%\checkedchar{\tikz[baseline={([yshift=-.8ex]current bounding box.center)}]\node[shape=circle,minimum size=8mm,draw] at (0,0) {} node at (0,0) {\thechoice\llap{$\surd$}};}
% Make checked box character bold
\checkedchar{\tikz[baseline={([yshift=-.8ex]current bounding box.center)}]\node[shape=circle,minimum size=8mm,draw] at (0,0) {} node at (0,0) {\thechoice};}
```

But this will not work for the `checkboxes` environment because it does not keep track of the items using a counter. For that, you have to modify the environment:

```
\makeatletter
    \renewenvironment{checkboxes}%
       {\setcounter{choice}{0}\list{\checkbox@char}%
          {%
            \settowidth{\leftmargin}{W.\hskip\labelsep\hskip 2.5em}%
            \def\choice{%
              \if@correctchoice
                \color@endgroup \endgroup
              \fi
              \stepcounter{choice}
              \item[\checked@char]
              \do@choice@pageinfo
            } % choice
            \def\CorrectChoice{%
              \if@correctchoice
                \color@endgroup \endgroup
              \fi
              \ifprintanswers
                % We can't say \choice here, because that would
                % insert an \endgroup.
                % 2016/05/10: We say \color@begingroup in addition to
                % \begingroup in case \CorrectChoiceEmphasis involves color
                % and the text exactly fills the line (which would
                % otherwise create a blank line after this choice):
                % 2016/05/11: We leave hmode if we're in it,
                % i.e., if there's no blank line preceding this
                % \CorrectChoice command.  (Without this, the
                % \special created by a \color{whatever} command that might
                % be inserted by \CorrectChoice@Emphasis would be appended 
                % to the previous \choice, which could cause an extra
                % (blank) line to be inserted before this \CorrectChoice.)
                % Since \par and \endgraf seem to cancel \@totalleftmargin
                % (for reasons I don't understand), we'll do the following:
                % Motivated by  the def of \leavevmode, 
                %      \def\leavevmode{\unhbox\voidb@x}
                % we will now leave hmode (if we're in hmode):
                \ifhmode \unskip\unskip\unvbox\voidb@x \fi
                \begingroup \color@begingroup \@correctchoicetrue
                \CorrectChoice@Emphasis
                \stepcounter{choice}
                \item[\checked@char]
              \else
                \stepcounter{choice}
                \item[\checked@char]
              \fi
              \do@choice@pageinfo
            } % CorrectChoice
            \let\correctchoice\CorrectChoice
            \labelwidth\leftmargin\advance\labelwidth-\labelsep
            \topsep=0pt
            \partopsep=0pt
            \checkboxeshook
          }%
       }%
       {\if@correctchoice \color@endgroup \endgroup \fi \endlist}
     \makeatother
```

And now for a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,answers]{exam}

\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{checkboxes}%
   {\setcounter{choice}{0}\list{\checkbox@char}%
      {%
        \settowidth{\leftmargin}{W.\hskip\labelsep\hskip 2.5em}%
        \def\choice{%
          \if@correctchoice
            \color@endgroup \endgroup
          \fi
          \stepcounter{choice}
          \item[\checked@char]
          \do@choice@pageinfo
        } % choice
        \def\CorrectChoice{%
          \if@correctchoice
            \color@endgroup \endgroup
          \fi
          \ifprintanswers
            % We can't say \choice here, because that would
            % insert an \endgroup.
            % 2016/05/10: We say \color@begingroup in addition to
            % \begingroup in case \CorrectChoiceEmphasis involves color
            % and the text exactly fills the line (which would
            % otherwise create a blank line after this choice):
            % 2016/05/11: We leave hmode if we're in it,
            % i.e., if there's no blank line preceding this
            % \CorrectChoice command.  (Without this, the
            % \special created by a \color{whatever} command that might
            % be inserted by \CorrectChoice@Emphasis would be appended 
            % to the previous \choice, which could cause an extra
            % (blank) line to be inserted before this \CorrectChoice.)
            % Since \par and \endgraf seem to cancel \@totalleftmargin
            % (for reasons I don't understand), we'll do the following:
            % Motivated by  the def of \leavevmode, 
            %      \def\leavevmode{\unhbox\voidb@x}
            % we will now leave hmode (if we're in hmode):
            \ifhmode \unskip\unskip\unvbox\voidb@x \fi
            \begingroup \color@begingroup \@correctchoicetrue
            \CorrectChoice@Emphasis
            \stepcounter{choice}
            \item[\checked@char]
          \else
            \stepcounter{choice}
            \item[\checked@char]
          \fi
          \do@choice@pageinfo
        } % CorrectChoice
        \let\correctchoice\CorrectChoice
        \labelwidth\leftmargin\advance\labelwidth-\labelsep
        \topsep=0pt
        \partopsep=0pt
        \checkboxeshook
      }%
   }%
   {\if@correctchoice \color@endgroup \endgroup \fi \endlist}
 \makeatother

% Make checkbox character a circle with the letter
\checkboxchar{\tikz[baseline={([yshift=-.8ex]current bounding box.center)}]\node[shape=circle,minimum size=8mm,draw] at (0,0) {\thechoice};}
% Make checked box character bold WITH surd
%\checkedchar{\tikz[baseline={([yshift=-.8ex]current bounding box.center)}]\node[shape=circle,minimum size=8mm,draw] at (0,0) {} node at (0,0) {\thechoice\llap{$\surd$}};}
% Make checked box character bold
\checkedchar{\tikz[baseline={([yshift=-.8ex]current bounding box.center)}]\node[shape=circle,minimum size=8mm,draw] at (0,0) {} node at (0,0) {\thechoice};}


\begin{document}
\begin{questions}

\question
Blah blah

\begin{checkboxes}\choice one
\choice two
\CorrectChoice three
\end{checkboxes}

\question
Blah blah

\begin{oneparcheckboxes}
\choice one
\choice two
\CorrectChoice three
\end{oneparcheckboxes}

\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

This will shows as:

[image: The showcase]