# How to write the option of for MCQs in latex as shown in picture?

Tags: lists

I am writing the MCQs for matric but I am getting problem how to write the MCQs option as shown in picture.
[image]

I am providing the total document of my codes and packages that is:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage[paperheight=10in,paperwidth=9in, top=1in, bottom=0.8in, twocolumn, twoside]{geometry}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[centertags]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}\graphicspath{{Graphics/}}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[square,sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{booktabs}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\newcommand\aug{\fboxsep=-\fboxrule\!\!\!\fbox{\strut}\!\!\!}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{Thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lem}[Thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{pro}[Thm]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{de}[Thm]{Definition}
\newtheorem{re}[Thm]{Remark}
\newtheorem{ex}[Thm]{Example}
\newtheorem{cor}[Thm]{Corollary}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\definecolor{uuuuuu}{rgb}{0.26666666666666666,0.26666666666666666,0.26666666666666666}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
%\include{frontmatter/colophon}
%\include{fronmatter/frontpiece}
%\include{frontmatter/dedication}
%\include{frontmatter/preface}
%\twocolumn
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\include{mainmatter/Chapter-1}
\include{mainmatter/Chapter-2}
\end{document}
```

I can not add the empty circle for MCQs option as shown in picture.

Comment: Almost [templates - How to create circle checkbox multiple choice exam with choice letters inside circle - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/567324/how-to-create-circle-checkbox-multiple-choice-exam-with-choice-letters-inside-ci) / https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34735/using-circled-numbers-for-answer-choices-in-exam-document-class

Comment: Looks like modifying the answer above to remove the item inside is sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do it with the `tasks` package, but with your page layout, you do not have the space to put 4 choices on the same line. I used `\begin{tasks}(2)`, but my choice texts are short.

I left your preamble, even if it is not minimal. Remember not to load packages twice.
The key instruction in the preamble are:

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{label=(\roman*).}% <-- This set the second level of enumerate with (i.), (ii.), etc.
\usepackage{tasks}
\settasks{label=$\circ$}% <-- This set the label of the horizontal list with a circle
```

Here the complete example:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage[paperheight=10in,paperwidth=9in, top=1in, bottom=0.8in, twocolumn, twoside]{geometry}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[centertags]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}\graphicspath{{Graphics/}}
%\usepackage{amsthm}<--- DO NOT LOAD PACKAGES TWICE!
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[square,sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{label=(\roman*).}
\usepackage{tasks}
\settasks{label=$\circ$}

%\usepackage{hyperref}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\newcommand\aug{\fboxsep=-\fboxrule\!\!\!\fbox{\strut}\!\!\!}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{Thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lem}[Thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{pro}[Thm]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{de}[Thm]{Definition}
\newtheorem{re}[Thm]{Remark}
\newtheorem{ex}[Thm]{Example}
\newtheorem{cor}[Thm]{Corollary}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\definecolor{uuuuuu}{rgb}{0.26666666666666666,0.26666666666666666,0.26666666666666666}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Some text
      \begin{enumerate}
      \item Some sub item
            \begin{tasks}(2)
            \task Choice A      
            \task Choice B
            \task Choice C
            \end{tasks}        
      \item Some other sub item
            \begin{tasks}(2)
            \task Choice D      
            \task Choice E
            \task Choice F
            \task Choice G
            \end{tasks}       
      \end{enumerate}
\item Some other text
      \begin{enumerate}
      \item Some sub item
            \begin{tasks}(2)
            \task Choice H      
            \task Choice I
            \task Choice J
            \task Choice K
            \task Choice L
            \end{tasks}       
      \item Some other sub item
            \begin{tasks}(2)
            \task Choice M      
            \task Choice N
            \end{tasks}       
      \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]